# Apply opacity filter on background image?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to apply an opacity over a background image on my web page.

How do I achieve this? I just want it solely on the image area.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5nfd2rp/).

**HTML:**

```
<header class="main-header " style="background-image:url('http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I00004urs0axX2VI/s/860/860/0801A130.jpg');">

        <div class="sticky-header">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="medium-10 columns primary menu">
                    <ul class="inline naked">
                        <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-header {
padding-top: 30px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-size: auto 100%;
border-bottom: 5px solid #f2f2f2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.main-header {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1480px;
position: fixed;
background-image: url("http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I00004urs0axX2VI/s/860/860/0801A130.jpg");
background-position-y: -30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto 100%;
background-position: center top;
position: relative;
transition: background-position ease-in 0.3s;
height: 720px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Apply the opacity to the element itself.

Comment: I had originally tried using `background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);` but that didn't work. I was going to mess around with having an additional `div` in there and filling the header area with it, setting a slight opacity on it.

Comment: no thats right you can only have color or Image

Comment: Is my 2nd idea a viable option here? :)

Comment: Im ormaly doing the seccond one or if ist always the same Image I edit the Image in GIMP etc

Comment: Wow, and it worked! http://jsfiddle.net/c5nfd2rp/1/

Comment: Only problem is 'semantically', it doesn't look great, eh? This `Pseudo` idea  that @Tambo just put up looks better to me :)

Comment: Better to add opacity in the image itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pseudo element since you can not apply opacity on the background in css

```css
.main-header {
height: 720px;
}

.sticky-header {
padding-top: 30px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-size: auto 100%;
border-bottom: 5px solid #f2f2f2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.main-header {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1480px;
position: fixed;
background-position-y: -30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto 100%;
background-position: center top;
position: relative;
transition: background-position ease-in 0.3s;
height: 720px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:1
}

.main-header:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I00004urs0axX2VI/s/860/860/0801A130.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: .4
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
     
    <div class="sticky-header">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="medium-10 columns primary menu">
                <ul class="inline naked">
                    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this excellent answer, @Tambo! I was wondering, can I still use this on a website where each page has a different background image?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Sure you can but you will have to add a class to each of them to be able to use different backgrounds.

Comment: That was my concern. I'll have a think. I could generate new classes depend on any new pages added to the system I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is not working on background images.
You can only use opacity on html elements.

So the best is to place background image inside a div without content and give the div an opacity value

```
<div style=position:relative;">

    <div id="position:absolute; left:0;top:0;background" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-image:url(/path/to/img);opacity:0.6; z-index:1">

    </div>

    <div id="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2"> 
        Your content here
    </div>
</div>
```